# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for JARs imported by Maven

Tags: java, maven

I imported JSON by Maven adding it to POM.XML, the file was downloaded to the folder "Maven Dependencies", despite the fact that the project is running without errors and import is okay, error appears server response:

*"GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/mavenDWP] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject"*

Picture:
[image: Maven Enviroment]

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>mavenDWP</groupId>
  <artifactId>mavenDWP</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180813</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `<scope>runtime</scope>` to your json dependency to make sure that your Tomcat or in other words you can access classes of this dependency out of your JSPs. Currently it carries the implicit scope `compile`.

If you have further issues like this one, please make sure to get also a good overview over the further [Maven scopes and their semantics](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope).

Answer (score 0):

First: your dependency declaration looks good, this implicit compile is correct.

Why are you running the very old tomcat7 with jdk10 - I'm sure this combination is not supported anymore.

I assume, it's a problem with your eclipse project settings - how the class path is configured. please have a look to the class path settings of you eclipse project "mavenDWP".

by the way: currently your project is creating its classpath out of two 'sources' - one source is maven, another source is the part contributed by eclipse (what is listed as Apache Tomcat v7.0 within "Libraries". This project will never work on it's own. Maybe you try first to create a pure web-project with maven (f.e. by using the https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-webapp/ and import it later into eclipse.

Comment: Is it here? I'm facing problems to know how to use it.
https://i.imgur.com/uvo9S37.png